# Issue with the Civilization V Gods and Kings tags

Tags: discussion, tags

An expansion pack to the game `Civilization V` has recently been released, called `Civilization V - Gods & Kings`. `Civilization V` is currently tagged [civilization-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5) and has [civ5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ5) as a synonym (`civ` is a common shorthand for the series). However, it appears someone made a problematic decision on how to tag the expansion - it's using [civ-5-gods-and-kings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-5-gods-and-kings).

What's so bad about it? Because if you look at an example question of mine, tagged with both:

[How do I convert a city to my religion?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74385/how-do-i-convert-a-city-to-my-religion)

The page's title will show both tags as a prefix:

> civilization 5 civ 5 gods and kings - How do I convert a city to my religion?

Looks a bit of a mess. So my questions are:

1. Is it something we want to fix? It looks messy but it does contain all the important keywords we want.
2. If we do fix it, are there any proposals what to?

   - The classical [civilization-5-gods-and-kings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5-gods-and-kings) is too long.
   - [civilization-5-gak](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5-gak) or [civilization-5-gk](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5-gk) are useful for auto-completing the tag name when asking a question, but less useful for Googlability.

Answer (score 4):

Retag [civilization-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5) (and possibly other games from the series the same way) to [civ-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-5). The series is recognizeable enough that this will be completely unambiguous. It's almost certain that google recognizes these as synonyms of each other, and most people searching for the game will probably only type "civ" anyway; the whole word is rather long. Then we can keep [civ-5-gods-and-kings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-5-gods-and-kings) as is, and someone specifically looking for the expansion on google will have a much better time of it.

Comment: Good idea, I like it!

Comment: [Pretty sure you're spot on with you assumption that google recognizes these two as synonyms](https://www.google.ca/search?q=civ&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: Alternatively, ask Jarrod to fiddle with his code so it considers synonyms as well.