# How should we tag Assassin's Creed 3 Liberation?

Tags: discussion, tags

With the release of the PS Vita title *Assassin's Creed 3: Liberation*, I find myself struggling on coming up with a good tag.

[assassins-creed-3-liberation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-3-liberation) is too long
[assassins-creed-3-lib](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-3-lib) doesn't look quite right
[ac3-liberation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac3-liberation) looks good, but it does away with our normal tagging scheme for Assassin's Creed titles, which is [assassins-creed-xyz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-xyz) where XYZ is an abbreviated version of the subtitle (revel for Revelations, and bh for Brotherhood).

**How should we tag this 28 (26 if you leave out the 3!) character title?**

Comment: Dang, `[assassins-creed-liberation]` is 1 off too.  I vote for `[ac3-liberation]` then.

Comment: Similar: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4957/issue-with-the-civilization-v-gods-and-kings-tags

Comment: @Oak I'd say, based on that, Assassin's Creed is known well enough that a complete overhaul of its tags would work. ac-brotherhood, ac-revelations, etc.

Comment: `[assassins-creed-3-vita]`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Alright, based on [Oak's related meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4957/issue-with-the-civilization-v-gods-and-kings-tags), and the popularity of the *Assassin's Creed* franchise, I'd like to propose the following solution:

- Keep [assassins-creed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed)
- Keep [assassins-creed-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-2)
- Create a Master tag for [ac-brotherhood](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-brotherhood), merging anything tagged [assassins-creed-bh](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-bh) and synonymizing [assassins-creed-bh](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-bh) with [ac-brotherhood](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-brotherhood)
- Follow these same steps for [ac-revelations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-revelations), merging/synonymizing [assassins-creed-revel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-revel)
- Keep [assassins-creed-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-3)
- Create [ac3-liberation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac3-liberation) and merge/synonymize [assassins-creed-3-lib](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-3-lib)

This will allow us to have each game tagged appropriately, with the full subtitle, keeping some sort of consistency without reducing our Google Juice.

Comment: More importantly, tag autocomplete will be useful for locating tags.

Comment: This is a great solution. A lot of times when I tag search for games like these, I type the name of that specific expansion (i.e. "liberation") without the "assassins-creed" part, so shortening those parts of the game title makes it harder to find the correct tags. Having both versions would account for whatever way a user types it.

Answer (score 4):

**I think we need more consistency in the naming of these kind of things in general**, using past examples with Mass Effect, we have the following different tags for the various games released:

- [mass-effect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect)
- [mass-effect-infiltrator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-infiltrator)
- [mass-effect-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-series)
- [mass-effect-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-2)
- [mass-effect-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3)
- [mass-effect-3-datapad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3-datapad)
- [mass-effect-3-from-ashes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3-from-ashes)
- [me3-resurgence-pack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/me3-resurgence-pack)
- [me3-leviathan](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/me3-leviathan)

As you can see, we don't reliably name tags within the same game series as it stands, and there are further examples of this for other games with various expansions/downloadable contents.

This causes further problems in locating the correct tag for a game, if you search on the [tag page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags) for Mass Effect, the tags starting me3 don't appear, in order to see these tags you must search for ME3.

In this case is fine because the abbreviation is well known, but in doing this you only find half of the downloadable content because we haven't named the tags in a consistent manner.

I think the answer to this question relies on setting a standard for tagging on Arqade in general, and **I am personally leaning towards initials-expansion-title** (ie: me3-leviathan, me3-omega, me3-from-ashes, ac3-liberation)

Comment: The only issue here is, until Liberation, we *have* followed a standard tag style for the Assassin's Creed games.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the 'standard tag style' changes from game to game, and could probably do with standardising.

Comment: One problem with across the board standardization is that often the best tag is the least abbreviated one. I think, for example, "mass-effect-3" is a better tag than "me3".

Comment: Oh I agree, but it's not better if you end up having half of the content under one tag format and the other using a different format altogether

Comment: We have a 25 character tag limit. There's an issue of "Mass-Effect-3" is fine, but when, 6 months later, Mass effect comes out with "Mass-Effect-3-Resurgence-Pack", we're suddenly at a loss. The previous naming schema cannot be used due to character limits. Should we retag all those other questions because there was one really long piece of DLC?

Comment: My point is, it's hard to provide consistency since it's not obvious when we will later need to add a related tag.

Comment: that's why I suggested going with the shorter option as the standard, there are valid reasons against doing this

Comment: This is why tags for most DLC and Expansions are unneccesary and a bad idea. AC has the unique issue of dozens of annoying spinoffs with long names. (See also: Final Fantasy)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>To me, the "most right" answer would be to allow a particular subset of users (10k+?) to create arbitrarily long tags.</strike>

My guess is that this is not something that can be changed without an overhaul of the Stack Exchange codebase, else it would have already been done.

Turns out you can't do this.  Thanks Invader Skoodge!

In that case, I say create [assassins-creed-3-liber](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-3-liber) and synonymize with [ac3-liberation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac3-liberation).  That way it keeps the series-number-title format.

Comment: They have stated multiple times that this is not happening, and it never will happen. We have to deal with the limits we have.

Comment: Oh.  Well that's a bummer.  Thanks for letting me know.