# Merge request: [assassins-creed-bh] to [ac-brotherhood]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merging

Per [this meta topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5576/how-should-we-tag-assassins-creed-3-liberation), I've created the tag [ac-brotherhood](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-brotherhood).

Can we merge all questions tagged [assassins-creed-bh](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-bh) into this new tag, and create a synonym?

Comment: i found this http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/reconsidering-how-we-tag-games-in-a-series

Comment: just realized how old this question is

Comment: @Paralytic This is point 4 in acton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been done. Apologies for the delay