# Rename [civ-*] → [civilization-*]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

There are a number of games in the *[Civilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_(series))* franchise that can be expanded thanks to the 35 character tag limit.

- [civilization-4-bts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-4-bts) → [civilization-4-beyond-the-sword](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-4-beyond-the-sword)
- [civ-4-colonization](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-4-colonization) → [civilization-4-colonization](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-4-colonization)
- [civ-5-brave-new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-5-brave-new-world) → [civilization-5-brave-new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5-brave-new-world)
- [civ-5-gods-and-kings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-5-gods-and-kings) → [civilization-5-gods-and-kings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5-gods-and-kings)

There is however *[Civilization: Beyond Earth — Rising Tide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization:_Beyond_Earth_%E2%80%93_Rising_Tide)* and [civilization-beyond-earth-rising-tide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-beyond-earth-rising-tide) is two characters too long. I think that the best we can do is expand [civ-be-rising-tide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-be-rising-tide) → [civilization-beyond-earth-rt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-beyond-earth-rt), or alternatively [civ-beyond-earth-rising-tide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-beyond-earth-rising-tide).

For reference, [Issue with the Civilization V Gods and Kings tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4957/47878) was a former question from when there was a 25 character tag limit, which isn't relevant now.

Comment: This is another one of those cases where I'm a bit torn between trying to fit the whole name, and having the names being consistent. I think, in this case, because the base game tags spell out 'Civilization' that we could go for consistency and do "Civ-X-_expansion-name_".

Comment: @Bob2Chiv What is your rationale for shortening the expansion names? Aside from *Civilization: Beyond Earth - Rising Tide*, they all fit within 35 characters. I'm not seeing how shortening the expansion names to `[civ-X-expansion-name]` is more consistent. Wouldn't the logger versions be more consistent, since it would match the base games?

Comment: I meant consistent with each other. If we do `civ-X-expansion-name` then `civ-be-rising-tide` would not need to change, but others would. "Civ X" is a pretty standard abbreviation from what I've heard [once again having never played the game(s)]. 

EDIT: Oh, I see you are saying consistency with the base games names

Comment: @Bob2Chiv Yes, I'm describing consistency with the base games. Also, we already have `[civilization-6-rise-and-fall]`, so not all expansions are the shorter versions. Also, Google seems to treat `civ` and `civilization` as synonyms, so we don't need to worry about SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are now done:

- [civilization-4-bts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-4-bts) → [civilization-4-beyond-the-sword](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-4-beyond-the-sword)
- [civ-4-colonization](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-4-colonization) → [civilization-4-colonization](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-4-colonization)
- [civ-5-brave-new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-5-brave-new-world) → [civilization-5-brave-new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5-brave-new-world)
- [civ-5-gods-and-kings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-5-gods-and-kings) → [civilization-5-gods-and-kings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5-gods-and-kings)
- [civ-be-rising-tide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-be-rising-tide), [civilization-beyond-earth-rt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-beyond-earth-rt) → [civ-beyond-earth-rising-tide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-beyond-earth-rising-tide)

I chose the short 'civ' tag for Rising tide as it has the most important words spelled out explicitly, whereas 'Civ' is already considered synonymous with 'Civilization'

Answer (score 6):

This answer's primary focus is on **full game name** throughout the tag names.

This answer is for renaming all of the tags to be of the form:

[civilization-x-expansion-name](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-x-expansion-name).

This would result in:

[civilization-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5) and [civilization-5-brave-new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5-brave-new-world),

[civilization-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-6) and [civilization-6-rise-and-fall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-6-rise-and-fall),

In cases where the full game name does not fit, each would be handled on a case by case basis.

I figured I might as well put this option as an answer so people can down or up vote appropriately.

Comment: At present, the only one that doesn't fit is `[civilization-beyond-earth-rising-tide]` (37 characters).

Answer (score 3):

This answer's primary focus is on consistency throughout **all** of the tag names.

This answer is for renaming all of the tags to be of the form:

[civ-x-expansion-name](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-x-expansion-name).

This would result in:

[civ-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-5) and [civ-5-brave-new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-5-brave-new-world),

[civ-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-6) and [civ-6-rise-and-fall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-6-rise-and-fall),

ETC

I figured I might as well put this option as an answer so people can down or up vote appropriately.

Answer (score -2):

This answer's primary focus is on consistency throughout **groups** of the tag names.

This answer is for renaming all of the base tags to be of the form:

[civilization-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-x).

And all the expansions to be of the form:

[civ-x-expansion-name](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-x-expansion-name).

This would result in:

[civilization-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5) and [civ-5-brave-new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-5-brave-new-world),

[civilization-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-6) and [civ-6-rise-and-fall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civ-6-rise-and-fall),

ETC

I figured I might as well put this option as an answer so people can down or up vote appropriately.